# Can I apply artificial gain to an image?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, camera

I am communicating with a USB camera via Python, but can not find a way to control the gain. I have tried pylablib, pyusb, opencv, and a few other libraries with no success (the manufacturer does not provide a working DLL). At this point I think my only option is to apply artificial gain to the image, but I'm not sure if this is even possible. My understanding is that gain is just the amplification of signal  on the camera's sensor, so I would expect to be able to just multiply the pixel intensities by some factor to achieve the same affect: `shown_img = (shown_img * 2.0).astype("uint8")`
...but this results in an image with random colors (attached image "weird.png"). I'm obviously doing something wrong here, but maybe my foundational understanding is incorrect.

Could anyone confirm that this is possible? If so what would be the proper array manipulation to apply gain? This doesn't need to be explained with Python, that is just what I've been using for this project.

Thank you in advance!

Original:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

After applying clipping method (suggested in comments):
[image]

Comment: Could it be that your image intensity is going over the range of uint8? For example, if you had a value of 128, if you multiply it by 2 and set it to uint8, it would be 0. Can you try clipping the values of the image so it would be lower or equal to 255?

Comment: good point! I used `shown_img = np.clip(shown_img * float(2.0), 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)` to clip the image between 0 and 255. This does seem to achieve more of the effect I am looking for, but I still see some banding artifacts that are unexpected. I will add another image above...

Comment: how about you play around with OpenCV's CAP_PROP_* properties

Comment: hi @ChristophRackwitz, I did try using opencv.VideoCapture to acquire image frames and adjust settings with the CAP_PROP_*. I could control exposure (although somewhat of a headache as you have to convert the raw value into mysterious units cv2 liked) and gamma. However when attempting to control gain, this always resulted in a return of -1 I believe. I tried all sorts of values thinking maybe cv2 needed this to be converted as well, but to no avail.

Comment: the return value `-1` means the native OS API can't do this (not an OpenCV issue), or (an OpenCV issue) nobody has bothered to implement that part of the native OS API in OpenCV.

Comment: Yep, that's why I'm trying to use post-processing to achieve a similar affect. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
shown_img = (shown_img * 2.0).astype("uint8")
```

scales the intensities and casts to 8-bit unsigned integer. This cast, when values exceed 255 (the largest value representable in a uint8) will wrap around. For example, casting 256 to uint 8 produces 0. This wrap around is what causes the weird colors you see.

To prevent the wrap around, you need to saturate the values, make those larger than 255 have a value of 255, before casting:

```
shown_img = 
shown_img[shown_img > 255] = 255
shown_img = shown_img.astype("uint8")
```

It might be easier to use the `np.clip` function:

```
shown_img = np.clip(shown_img * 2.0, 0, 255).astype("uint8")
```

Comment: Hi Cris. Thanks for the suggestion! I did try this after Jongsung's similar comment, but it still doesn't have the same affect as applying gain through the software. As shown above there seems to be banding artifacts in the processed image.

Comment: @ekorb That is expected. Those bands exist in the input, but you can't see them there because the step size is 1. You have scaled the intensities, so each step in the input is more clearly visible now. The stronger the gain change, the more strongly this banding will become visible. You are also scaling the noise. This is not a substitute for changing the gain in the camera itself.